# MySQL stored procedure / Automatic delete table

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a table on mysql that is being automatically updated. How can I define an automatic script that will:

"DELETE FROM tbl"

every week or so?

Comment: See the event scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CRON jobs. You can write the delete statement in a separate php file and tell the server to run that php file every week.

Comment: Well, depending on OS

Comment: What if I wanted MySQL to do it? based on some limitations we have, we can't depend on external scripts.